# Time series database in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, time-series

I know it's not the best candidate, but is it possible to use MySQL as a relational database to create a Time series database ?

Comment: Google for:  time series database in mysql

Comment: I didn't find anything useful @HoneyboyWilson

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is a very capable RDBMS, though I'd use MariaDB if you can. Depending on the level of throughput you require, it should have no issue handling your data pipeline.

Time series are nothing more than a sequence of write operations. So long as your sequence gaps are larger than the smallest time discrepancy (MS), than there shouldn't be any issue.

Comment: Why would you use MariaDB over MySQL 8.0?

Comment: Well, at least that's honest :-(